# Wrong Word Usage

Tags: single-word-requests

What is it called when someone says a word which means the opposite of what happened.  Example:  I missed every light on the way to work.  Technically, that means you had to stop for every light.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you're asking here. Are you looking for something along the same lines as "lying"? Or are you asking about something else entirely?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying you think someone would actually say *I missed every light* when really they mean *I had to wait at every light?* I've never heard that one, but it doesn't seem like a typical "ironic" usage where you might say *I had **a few** delays* when what you really mean is you had a ***lot*** of delays.

Comment: *Missed the light* is a common term in the U.S. It means *missed the green light (not to mention the yellow light) and *got caught"* on the red light (and therefore had to stop).

Comment: Do you mean a **malapropism**?

Comment: I am not aware of a name for this, but in this case it is the simple result of a word being made implicit rather than explicit. Here the implicit word is green; the sentence "I missed the light" really means "I missed the green light." I'm leaving out the complicating factor of the yellow light, but it's fair to say the driver missed that, too. The result: Driver "caught on" red light. There may be explanations of this sort for other words that appear to indicate the opposite of what happened.

Comment: I read through this question a few times and now I feel like I don't understand English anymore. Please try explaining it to me like I don't already know what on Earth you are talking about. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that English has distilled that concept to a single word.  If it had, we would have heard of it in the *literally/figuratively* kerfuffle over the last few years.

I know of a few more words commonly misused that way (for instance, many people think *peruse* means to idly skim some text, when it actually means to read thoroughly), and I haven't heard the idea described with the single word.

Answer (score 0):

There's a word for this general concept: *paradoxical*.  Perhaps with some creativity one could use this word to express your idea.  For example:

> Missing every single green light on the way to work **is paradoxically expressed** as "missing* every light on the way to work.

I had never thought of this phrase that way, and I still don't quite see it the way you do.  However, I am aware of a word used by campesinos in Mexico that paradoxically expresses a very different idea from the literal meaning (*casualmente*).  By thinking of this word, I can relate to the idea you are asking about.